# Rails order by calculation in associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m working with the below Rails Models.

```
Artist.rb
has_many: updates

Update.rb
belongs_to: artist
```

Updates has a popularity column (int 0-100)

I need to order artists by difference in popularity within the last 30 days. (last row - first row of updates in range)

I’ve made this work in controller by iterating over list of artists, calculate the difference in popularity, and save that value together with the artist id in a new array. Then sort that array by increase value and recreate the list of artists in the correct order. Issue is this causes a timeout error on my application as the iteration happens upon clicking “search”.

Method to calculate difference:

```
class Update < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :artist

    def self.pop_diff(a)
        in_range = joins(:artist).where(artists: {name: a}).where(created_at:  30.days.ago.to_date..Time.now().to_date)
        diff = in_range.last.popularity - in_range.first.popularity
        return diff
    end

end
```

Creating a new array in controller with correct ordering:

```
@artists = Artist.all
@ordering = Array.new
@artists.each do |a|
    @ordering << {"artist" => a, "diff" => Update.pop_diff(a) } 
end

@ordering = @ordering.sort_by { |k| k["diff"]}.reverse!
```

Does anyone know best practice on dealing with these types of situations?

These are the three paths I can think of:

1. Tweaking above solution to work more efficiently
2. Using a virtual column (attr_accessor) and storing the increase there. I’ve never done this before, not sure what’s possible
3. Build a back-end script that saves increase value in database on a daily base.

Comment: Presuming you are saving everything correctly you can just query it with `Artist.includes(:update).order("updates.popularity desc").limit(100)` or some sane limit.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding though can you post some code?

Comment: Each artist has several rows of updates. One popularity value per day. So just ordering by popularity wouldn't cut it, will need to perform a calculation to get the difference in popularity for each artist between today & 30 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this approach you took has a problem with slow performance, in part because of the many queries you execute in the DB. Here's a simple way to do that (or very close to):

```
artists = Artist.all
pops =
  artists.
    includes(:updates).
    where('updates.created_at' => 30.days.ago..Time.zone.now).
    pluck(:id, 'updates.popularity').
    group_by {|g| g.first}.
    flat_map do |id, list|
      diffs = list.map(&:second).compact
      {
        artist: artists.find { |artist| artist.id == id},
        pops: diffs.last - diffs.first
      }
    end

# => [{:artist=>#<Artist id: 1, name: "1", created_at: "2018-07-10 05:44:29", updated_at: "2018-07-10 05:44:29">, :pops=>[10, 11, 1]}, {:artist=>#<Artist id: 2, name: "2", created_at: "2018-07-10 05:44:32", updated_at: "2018-07-10 05:44:32">, :pops=>[]}, {:artist=>#<Artist id: 3, name: "3", created_at: "2018-07-10 05:44:34", updated_at: "2018-07-10 05:44:34">, :pops=>[]}]
```

Much much more performant! But notice this is still not the most performant way to do the job. Still, it is very quick (although a little bit algebraic - you can improve somewhat) and uses a lot of the ruby and rails tricks to achieve the result you're looking for. Hope it helps! =)

Comment: The artists shouldn't be sorted by created_at only updates associated with an artist. Have yet to try your suggestion though, it might work still using artists = Artist.all ?

Comment: Gotcha. Edited @OscarSidebo !

Comment: This works & result coming back has correct array of popularity values.  Need to turn the array of popularity values into a single value which is last popularity value - first popularity value (difference) . Is that possible to do with you code?

Comment: I tried editing like this
pops: list.map(&:second).compact.last - list.map(&:second).compact.first

It works but may be a better way?

Comment: Sure, but to avoid repetition I'd rather do `pop_diffs = list.map(&:second).compact` outside the hash (the {}). Then inside the hash you just use `pop_diffs.last - pop_diffs.first` and voilà!

Comment: Great! Now my last question would be how to actually order by :pops? .order is not working since this it's an array now. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `order_by` for hashes. Take a look at http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash

Answer (score 1):

It would be most performant to do this in SQL

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  def self.get_popularity_extreme(direction = 'ASC', days_ago = 30)
    <<-SQL
      SELECT popularity
      FROM updates
      WHERE updates.created_at BETWEEN (DATEADD(DAY, -#{days_ago.to_i.abs}, NOW()), NOW())
      ORDER BY updates.created_at #{direction.presence || 'ASC'}
      LIMIT 1
    SQL
  end

  def self.by_popularity_difference
    joins(
      <<-SQL
        LEFT JOIN (
          #{get_popularity_extreme}
        ) earliest_update ON updates.artist_id = artists.id
        LEFT JOIN (
          #{get_popularity_extreme('DESC')}
        ) latest_update ON updates.artist_id = artists.id
      SQL
    ).
    where('earliest_update.popularity IS NOT NULL').
    where('latest_update.popularity IS NOT NULL').
    select('artists.*', 'latest_update.popularity - earliest_update.popularity AS popularity_difference').
    order('popularity_difference DESC')   
  end
end
```

Of course this is not the 'rails way'

The other option I would take would be to add a trigger to `Update` `after_save` to also set a column in the parent artist table

```
class Update < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :artist
    after_save :set_artist_difference

    def self.pop_diff(a)
        in_range = where(artist_id: a.id).where(created_at:  30.days.ago.to_date..Time.now().to_date).limit(1)
        in_range.order(created_at: :desc).first.popularity - in_range.order(:created_at).first.popularity
    end

    def set_artist_difference
      artist.update(difference: self.class.pop_diff(a))
    end
end
```

the downside to this is if not every artist gets an update every day, the number won't be accurate

If you are to continue using your current solution, you should specify the order, explicit return is unnecessary, you shouldn't lookup an artist you already have, and the join isn't needed, (and also it's just wrong because your passing the whole artist, yet filtering it on 'name'):

```
class Update < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :artist

    def self.pop_diff(a)
        in_range = where(artist_id: a.id).where(created_at:  30.days.ago.to_date..Time.now().to_date).limit(1)
        in_range.order(created_at: :desc).first.popularity - in_range.order(:created_at).first.popularity
    end
end
```

also instead of sorting the opposite direction then reversing, sort by negative diff:

```
@artists = Artist.all
@ordering = Array.new
@artists.find_in_batches do |batch|
    batch.each do |a|
        @ordering << {"artist" => a, "diff" => Update.pop_diff(a) } 
    end
end

@ordering = @ordering.sort_by { |k| -(k["diff"])}
```

Comment: Thanks @SampsonCrowley. The edits you've done makes total sense, thank you.

As far as the SQL suggestion on top, how would I run that? Directly in Rails Console or do I have to create method for join_query in Update Model?

Comment: What I posted in my answer is a lambda (notice the `join_query.call` inside the Aritst lookup), however it would probably be best to make it a function in the Artist model. I'll post and update soon

Comment: @OscarSidebo updated answer to use class methods in the Artist model.